# Switching intent

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an application that will use 2 activities. The start or main activity sets up a bluetooth connection. When I switch to another activity I loose the bluetooth connection. Can a bluetooth connection be maintained when switching? Here is the OnResume() and onPause(). When I remove the btSocket.close() in the onPause The connection is maitained but will not communicate when onResume tries to connect.

```
    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
      try {
          final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
          return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
      }
  }
  return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

  BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);


try {
    btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
} catch (IOException e) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
}

 btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

try {
  btSocket.connect();
  Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
} catch (IOException e) {
  try {
    btSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e2) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
  }
}

// Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
mConnectedThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();

Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

try     {
  btSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e2) {
  errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your bluetooth connection independent of your activities.  I would suggest that you put all your bluetooth code into a 'MyApp' class derived from Android Application class, or into a service.  Using a service will be more complicated, but it will give you options to keep the app running even after the user closes the activities, e.g. if you want to finish your bluetooth communication.

You will find much written about both options, as they are common ways to structure your app - particularly when there is some form of network communication.

Comment: Tom, thanks for the tip.  here is some good information on the service http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html